# drag and zoom scatter plot in highcharts shiny R

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to create a scatter plot in which I could be able to drag an area and see in a table the data from the dragged points as also as to zoom in that specific area.

After a research on the internet, I came to a solution with gglopt2 which works nice (presented next) and performs all the features I described.

Now I'm wondering if I could do the same using the highcharts package on shiny R. I searched on the internet but I found no solution to my problem. Could someone help me on this?

Thanks in advance

```
library(ggplot2)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # global variable, what type of plot interaction
  interaction_type <- "click"

  # observe for user interaction and change the global interaction_type
  # variable
  observeEvent(input$user_click, interaction_type <<- "click")
  observeEvent(input$user_brush, interaction_type <<- "brush")

  observeEvent(input$plot1_dblclick, {
    brush <- input$user_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      ranges$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
      ranges$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)

    } else {
      ranges$x <- NULL
      ranges$y <- NULL
    }
  })



  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
  })

  # generate the data to put in the table
  dat <- reactive({

    user_brush <- input$user_brush
    user_click <- input$user_click

    if(interaction_type == "brush") res <- brushedPoints(mtcars, user_brush)
    if(interaction_type == "click") res <- nearPoints(mtcars, user_click, threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1)

    return(res)

  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(dat()[,c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")]))

}


ui <- fluidPage(

  h3("Click or brush the plot and it will filter the table"),
  plotOutput("plot", click = "user_click", dblclick = "plot1_dblclick", brush = brushOpts(  id = "user_brush",   resetOnNew = TRUE       ) ),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a simple wrapper that will allow panning in both vertical and horizontal ways. In [`afterSetExtremes`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) events of axes you could get current extremes that could be passed to your table to filter data in the table.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u9on8dbb/